# Flutter - Navigate back to homepage and clear websocket connections - popUntil

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

I have developed a flutter web application that makes use of WebSockets. There is a button that is used to return to the landing page of the website, I have used popUntil to achieve this which works well but I have found that if I monitor the network tab, all the socket connections are still open.

I have tried to override dispose() to close the websocket connections but then I found that if I continue to use the website then I have multiple instances of other pages open with different websocket connections.

Is there a way in flutter web to essentially navigate to a page and completely destroy the navigation stack and all the views/states? Even just being able to launch redirect and refresh to the landing page in the same tab (resetting everything) would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue (for me ServerSocket to listen) follow this step:

Before leave page you have to close also  Server and  client var

i call this method before leave the page
you declare on top:
late ServerSocket server;
late Socket client;

```
void closeAllSocket(){
  server.close();
  client.destroyed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the socket instance to null before leaving the page where you invoked its instance. Not just in the dispose() method (disposed is called when the state of the page is destroyed) but also before routing out of that page as well. Only then it will not run in the background.

Comment: This still doesn't work. The issue is that when I go back to the page after traversing from the root page, it seem like multiple instances of that page are open are multiple socket instances open. So if I go back and fourth 5 times, even though I'm setting all sockets to null, there are 5 socket connections open and sending data.  It would be a lot easier if I could just reset the whole app on navigation back to root, as if someone hit refresh. on the tab

Comment: Oh I see, that is a different question in on itself though. What you need is a singleton class for this. You can't just create multiple instance of those sockets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it easy to 'retrofit' an existing stateful widget and make it a singleton? I thought that if you didn't pass a UniqueKey then it was always reusing the same stateful widget? (perhaps I misunderstood, I am new to Flutter)

Comment: You can open up a dev tool debugger and see how many of your state class exists in the stack page. Whenever `initState()` is called in the class, a new instance of that widget is created and pushed on top of that stack. You can confirm this by just routing multiple times to the same state class and popping back to see that different instances of that same state class exists in the stack. So, if you're using animations, streams, or socket, etc, that means they're being called every-time the new state class is initialized.

Comment: i have the same problem in the secondary page , with serversocket that was listen,when i pop remained listen to. this means that the widget remain unmounted from the second open